# Supervised classification, more classes than instances

Tags: python-3.x, classification, supervised-learning

I have a data set with 400 instances and 1335 classes, so each instance has more than one class. I want to implement a supervised classification algorithm that indicates the degree of belonging of each instance to each class. I had thought to use Fuzzy C-Means of skfuzzy (https://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/auto_examples/plot_cmeans.html), but it does not convince me at all.

Any help or idea is welcome, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem falls under the category of multi-label classification. 
You could create [multi-hot vector](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) as target variable and then use this target variable for one of the classifiers in sklearn, which supports [multi-label classification](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multiclass).